# Does dm-crypt support journaling filesystem transactional guarantees?

Tags: lvm, encryption, ext4, disk-encryption

I'm considering using ext4 on encrypted LVM (which uses LUKS and dm-crypt).  Will the transactional guarantees in ext4's journaling be preserved?

Bonus: where may I find authoritative information on this (besides the source)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does, according to the reply on the dm-crypt mailing list: http://www.saout.de/pipermail/dm-crypt/2012-April/002441.html

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I'm not 100 % sure regarding what kind of EXT4 transactional guarantees you're talking about, I'd suggest trying mounting with *write barriers* turned on (by default, IIRC) and see whether it's supported.

Comment: By transactional guarantees I just mean the generic guarantees made by any journaling filesystem such as ext4 - namely that the FS can always be in (or rather be quickly replayed/rolled back into) a consistent and uncorrupted state thanks to the journal. I assume that the write ordering setting (eg write barriers) is definitely respected.